How to initialise a list defined at the class level from a common method outside of the class in python?
I have a list defined at the class level in Python and below is my code:
class TestStudentReg(unittest.TestCase):
    student_id_list = []  

I'm trying to initialise the list by reading values from a csv file and below is the method that i use within the same class i.e., TestStudentReg
@classmethod
def initialise_student_id_list(cls):
    filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'        
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
        next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
        for col in datareader:
            cls.student_id_list.append(col[2])

Now that this method is being common across several classes, i'm planning to make it as a reusable function and define it in a separate python file (utilities.py) which will be like this:
import csv
import logging
import time
import timeit

def get_date(dateformat="%Y-%m-%d", subtract_num_of_days=0):
   getdate = date.today() - timedelta(subtract_num_of_days)
   return getdate.strftime(dateformat)

def initialise_student_id_list(**kwargs):  
    filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'      
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
        next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
        for col in datareader:
            cls.student_id_list.append(col[2])

I would like to understand how to initialise student_id_list from the utilities file.
One way i thought to implement this was to have the method return a list and initialise the value by calling this method.
def initialise_student_id_list(**kwargs):  
        id_list=[] 
        filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'     
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
            next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
            for col in datareader:
                cls.student_id_list.append(col[2])
        return id_list

Not sure if this is a correct approach. Great if someone could help me on this please.

Where did the filename variable in your class method come from? Please [edit] to show where it is defined.

What is the point of moving a method of a class out of the module the class is defined in, and into its own module? I understand that you expect multiple classes to make use of it, but the technique to use there is to inherit from a class that has the method defined - if you insist on putting it in a separate module, put a class in that module and make TestStudentReg a descendent of that class.

@Grismar Mostly, I agree with you. But there are some cases where it is not appropriate to inherit from the class. For example, if there is some class that needs this functionality but has nothing to do with what TestStudentReg is doing? I think a class method is not a good choice in the first place, and moving it to its own module may actually be a lot better.

When a function expects a class to be passed in as an argument and then starts modifying the content of that class (which is what OP's code does), it is only useful in the context of such a class, and it is certainly not better to write it as an independent function. Of course, you could completely rewrite it to become an independent function or class unto itself which could be composed into the other class - but then we're basically saying "you need something else altogether" and that's exchanging opinions, and not answering a question.

@Grismar I agree. Sorry for the earlier comment, but anyway, I think I can answer OP's question.

There are multiple ways to solve your problem. Here I will list three with increasing readability and overall quality:
def student_id_list_initialiser(class_obj, **kwargs):
    cls = class_obj   
    filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'      
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
        next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
        for col in datareader:
            cls.student_id_list.append(col[2])

class MyTest():
    student_id_list = []
    
    @classmethod
    def initialise_student_id_list(cls):
        student_id_list_initialiser(cls)

This approach works fine, but it isn't the best because we have to manually pass-in the class object and the code breaks encapsulation. However, if coupled with a simple and short classmethod that sets the class variable student_id_list, it will be better:
def student_id_list_creator(**kwargs):
    ret_l = []
    filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'      
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
        next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
        for col in datareader:
            ret_l.append(col[2])
    return ret_l

class MyTest():
    student_id_list = []
    
    @classmethod
    def initialise_student_id_list(cls):
        cls.student_id_list = student_id_list_creator()

This is similar to what you said you thought of, and yes, it is indeed a good approach.
Finally, inheritance is perhaps the best option here, although not a direct inheritance from the TestStudentReg class. Here's the code:
class StudentInfoHelper():
    @classmethod
    def initialise_student_id_list(cls):
        filename = 'input/student_testdata.csv'        
        with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
            datareader = (csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter="|"))
            next(datareader, None)  # skip the headers
            for col in datareader:
                cls.student_id_list.append(col[2])

class TestStudentReg(StudentInfoHelper):
    student_id_list = []

# outside:
TestStudentReg.initialise_student_id_list()

This code is not only more readable but also is much more flexible and can be applied to any class as long as the class inherit from StudentInfoHelper. The only downside to this approach is that

You must name your class variable student_id_list. But since you already decided the variable name, it wouldn't be a problem.
It wouldn't work if you define a method named student_id_initialiser. The reason is pretty obvious here: because if you do, then the original method will be "shadowed" by the new one. But sometimes, this is also a good thing if you want to custom the method or if you don't want it.


This is great - thank you. In the third approach, why do we call the method TestStudentReg.initialise_student_id_list() outside? Should it be within the TestStudentReg class?

@BalajiVenkatachalam Probably. If you have a __init__() method or other initializer, then place it there. Because I don't know the other parts of your class, so I just putted the method call outside. In practice, it is supposed to be within some method of the TestStudentReg class.
